# tag word with NLTK stanford NER

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp

I would like tag only a word and not a sentence with NLTK standford NER.

With `stNER.tag(word)` I have this output:

```
[[('o', 'O')], [('u', 'O')], [('r', 'O')]]
```

and I want `[('Our','O')]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe problem is that you provide `word` as a **string object not list**. Probably you should pass it like `stNER.tag(word.split())`. `word.split()` will return list which is an iterable object that this function requires.

But it's only guess you should provide bigger context (imports, type of variable `word`)

Comment: @customer_user that's might not be correct if there's more than one word in the input string.

Comment: Putting the string into a list would work only for single words. The correct thing to do is to perform word tokenization before that. The cheapest way to do it without additional function is `str.split()`, i.e. `stNER.tag(word.split())`

Comment: That is true, it will work only for this particular case. Better to do `split()` or tokenize method.

Comment: @custom_user, could you change your answer to use `split()` instead? Or could you explain that wrapping the string in the list only works for this particular scenario? That way, future users won't be misguided. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The input for the tagger function is list of strings `list(str)` not string `str`:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
text = 'our'
stner.tag(word_tokenize(text))
```